# API not in Json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, youtube

I'm using this API: https://decapi.me/youtube/latest_video?id=UCFaV5im11vfhDs1BaaF9a0A which gets the latest youtube video of a user, but it's not in JSON so I'm not sure how I would retrieve the data. I'm using `node-fetch` by the way.

Comment: You can parse the response string, if you are getting the response in consistent format.

Answer (score 0):

[node-fetch documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) :

> Decode content encoding (gzip/deflate) properly, and convert string output (such as res.text() and res.json()) to UTF-8 automatically.

Try res.text() ?